# I tried to upload my app on google play but got "invalid_privacy_policy.TITLE" issue over mail. what to do as i could not see solution on google

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, privacy-policy

Recently i tried to upload my app in google play but received the following issues over mail.

```
Property invalid_privacy_policy.TITLE not found 
Property invalid_privacy_policy.SHORT_DESCRIPTION not found
Property invalid_privacy_policy.POLICY_NAME not found
```